# How to retrieve data in jquery from mvc list type of model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class like below:

```
public class CustomBenefitCommittee
{
    public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
    public bool PropertyError { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using this class as a list type in MVC model like:

```
@model List<CustomBenefitCommittee>
```

I want to retrieve data from this model in jQuery. I am trying right now as

```
@{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(Model);
}

var model = @Html.Raw(json);
if(model != null && @Html.Raw(json) != "undefined")
{
    $.each(model, function () {
        alert(model.PropertyError );
    });
}
```

This is giving me undefind. Can someone help me out getting the values from this model.

Comment: `var model = @Html.Raw(Json,Encode(Model)); $.each(model, function(index, item) { alert(item.PropertyError); });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke `var model = @Html.Raw(Json,Encode(Model));` This part gives an error of `;, Json and Encode`.

Comment: `Json.Encode` (dot not comma - typo in comment above). And the syntax error for the `;` can be ignored - its just VS not recognizing perfectly valid code.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid, You added the correct solution in your edit (OP's issue is that `model.PropertyError` is `undefined` because `model` is the collection, not an item in the collection) but you immediately deleted it :) - it was your original answer that was wrong

Comment: I thought I was wrong that's why I removed the answer, I undo that delete.

Answer (score 1):

Make a loop like this:

```
 $.each(model, function(key, value) { alert(value.PropertyError); });
```

It will work.

Comment: I could be wrong, can you explain the reason for downvoting, I might learn something which I don't.

Comment: Converting it to a string and then parsing it back again is pointless.

Comment: I got it. That was my thought too before I was testing but whenever I do `JSON.parse`, it gives correct result but with only `@Html.Raw` It doesn't. There could be some other issue.

Comment: Just delete the original bit (which is pointless) - its the last code snippet which is correct.

Comment: Edited the answer and thumbs up for you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Make an method in you controller that returns model list (in json format) like:

```
public JsonResult LoadList()
{
   var modelList=new List<CustomBenefitCommittee>();
   modelList=   //get your list of model
   var jsonResult = Json(modelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   return jsonResult;
}
```

Now on View call this method throught jquery like:

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON('/"Controller Name"/"Action Name as "LoadList', function (data) {

 if (data.length == 0) {
 alert('No data');
 }
 else{
 $(data).each(function() {
 alert(this.PropertyError);
 });
 }

 });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Server Side:
First you need to add actions in the controller returns JsonResult.

```
public JsonResult GetData(int id)
{
    var data = new 
    {
      id,
      age = 23
    }
    return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

From Client Side:
you need ajax call to retrieve the data

```
function getData(id){
   var data = {id: id};
   $.get('/Home/GetData/', data,
         function (response) {
             alert(JSON.stringify(response));
             },'json'
    };
}
```

**OR**
if you are sending data to model and you want to use it in your javascript or jquery code you can use NewtonSoft.Json.

First install the Package in your solution:

```
PM> install-package NewtoSoft.Json
```

Second you can make your view like this:

```
@model ...
@using Newtonsoft.Json

<script type="text/javascript">

    var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model));

</script>
```

than you can use this data like this:

```
$.each(model, function(index, item) { alert(item.PropertyError); });
```

**And**
also you can use one the javascript frameworks like [Konockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [angularjs](http://angularjs.org)